# Do only one time in multiple Kubernetes pods

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes

I have a general question in optimization in having multiple Kubernetes pods. I have a Java application `service A` which checks on `service B` every 5 mins for a condition to do `task T`. Every 5 mins, if the condition is met, I want `task T` to be run.

However, `service A` currently run with 4 pods, and each of them are checking `service B` separately, and performing `task T` if condition is met. But the `task T` needs only to be performed one time if the condition on `service B` is met.

I am wondering if there's a way for different pods of `service A` to coordinate and only do `task T` one time every 5 mins (if condition is true), instead of 4 times done by each pod.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May I ask why is it necessary for you to run this apparently periodic service with a 4 pod deployment?

A better idea would be to use a `CronJob` instead that runs every 5 minutes and performs the task you want it to. Every time the `CronJob` is to run it will spawn a pod, which will check the condition on `Service B`, run the task if needed and decommission itself.

I don't see why you want to have 4 pods of a service that is basically a cron job.

You can find details on `CronJobs` [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/).

Comment: Definitely the micro service approach

Comment: Thank you zer0. Looks like this `CronJob` is the correct approach. I will look it up.